# How to view the contents of .dat file in linux

Tags: linux

I have a file with .dat extension how can i view the contents of the file in hexa ? mean if i open the file i should be able to see the contents in hex format, can this be done using vim editor. I have installed tnef but when i try opening this dat file it says "Seems not to be a TNEF file"

Comment: That depends on what the file *is*. `.dat` is such a generic extension that it could be anything. Where did you get the file *from*? What type of data do you *expect* to be contained in the file?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the dat file can be anything.

Use `file <yourfile>.dat` to find what it is. Then depending out its type, use specific application to open it.

```
mplayer <yourfile>.dat
gedit <yourfile>.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

Some common Linux utilities for viewing hex dumps are:

- xxd
- hexdump

Comment: +on kde: okteta

Answer (score 2):

`file` is a good command to try first.

After that, I use `cat -v | less` or `od -a | less` for a "readable" view.
Check the `man` pages for `od` and `file`.

`xxd` is more modern than `od`, and often generates a prettier view, but sometimes only `od` is available.

Answer (score 0):

Of course mc (in many serious distros available from basic install CD) has HEX viewer. It can be accessed id view mode by F4

Answer (score 0):

> **can this be done using vim editor[?].**

Here's one way, from [some blog Google found](http://www.linuxinstead.com/blog/2009/04/21/using-vi-as-a-hex-editor/)

> So, open a file in vi as usual, hit escape and type: `:%!xxd` to switch
>   into hex mode
>
> And when your [sic] done hit escape again and type: `:%!xxd -r` to exit from
>   hex mode.
>
> Okay, so this isn’t actaully switching to vi’s ‘hex mode’; vi doesn’t
>   have one. What the above actually does is to stream vi’s buffer
>   through the external program ‘xxd’.

A commenter added

> Try adding the following to `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`, and you’ll get
>   keyboard shortcuts for switching back and forth (F8 and F7).
>
> ```
> " Switch to hex-editor`
> noremap <F8> :%!xxd<CR> 
> " Switch back 
> noremap <F7> :%!xxd -r<CR>
> ```

There is also a [Vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_dump) on this subject.

Answer (score -3):

rename the file.
like  abc.dat to abc.pdf it will show the contents.

Comment: This only holds true if the file is a PDF; binary .dat files which are not PDFs won't display this way.